# Chrome throws ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when Apache redirects HttpS request to http

Tags: apache, google-chrome, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

How to allow redirection of https request to an apache webserver to http url without browsers throwing the below exception

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I tried the below configuration in httpd.conf

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
SSLVerifyClient optional
SSLVerifyDepth 3

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} !^SUCCESS$
RewriteRule ^.*\.js$ /newRedirectedForJS.php [L]    

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=off
RewriteRule ^.*\.js$ /newRedirectedForJS.php [L]
```

Edit:1

**Eg**:

From anothersite.com  a link to mysite is "https:// myserver.com/req.php" but i want to redirect that request in my apache webserver to " http:// myserver.com.redirect.php"

Comment: Is there any http server running on port 80 at all? Maybe only https is enabled.

Comment: yes, httpd is running on port 80. From another site, the link coming to my server is " https :// myserver.com/request.php", but i need to redirect with a " http :// myserver.com/newRedirect.php"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to redirect, not just rewrite, because you're changing the port (you would need to proxy the request if you want to keep the original https URL but I'm not even sure it would work).

In order to achieve that, make sure you change `[L]` to `[L,R]`.
You probably want to specify it's a permanent redirect, unless you plan on switching back to https later.

So in the end if would look like `[L,R=301]`